# How to make a generic NxM signed array multiplier using verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I did a 8 bit by 8 bit before,but it was not generic. i cant figure out how to adjust the code to make it NxM bit . can anyone help me?

Comment: You'll increase your chances of getting an answer if you add some code and show what you tried to make it generic.

Comment: Parameterize your code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use *parameters*. Parameters are basically input constants and are a good way of writing generic code. They sit between the name of the module and the ports in a list that looks like the port list, but is preceded by a hash:

```
module <MODULE NAME> #(<SOME TYPE> <PARAMETER NAME>=<DEFAULT_VALUE>, ...) (<THE PORTS>);
```

The ports themselves can be declared using the parameters. It is common to use a parameter to, for example, define the widths of inputs and outputs.

Here is an example (using an MxN multiplier):

```
module MULT #(integer M=8, integer N=8) (input [M-1:0] A, [N-1:0] B, [(M+N)-1:0] F);

  assign F = A * B;

endmodule
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Bvx

So, it's very easy if you're happy to just synthesize your multiplier. If your multiplier design is more structural, then you're going to have to learn about `generate` loops.